# Excel VBA - Copy Listobject values between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code which works fine on the same workbook.

```
Sub san_import(owb As Workbook, nwb As Workbook, sha As Worksheet, lis As String, col As Long, res As Long, Optional ByVal off As Long = 0)
Dim orng As ListObject
Dim nrng As ListObject
Dim r_fix As Long
Dim c_fix As Long
Dim i, o As Long

With owb
    Set orng = sha.ListObjects(lis)
    orng.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With

With nwb
    Set nrng = sha.ListObjects(lis)
    nrng.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With

r_fix = orng.ListRows.Count - nrng.ListRows.Count
c_fix = orng.ListColumns.Count - nrng.ListColumns.Count

With nwb
    If r_fix > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To r_fix
           nrng.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        Next i
    End If

    If c_fix > 0 Then
        For o = 1 To c_fix
           nrng.ListColumns.Add
        Next o
    End If

    sha.Activate
    sha.Range("A1").Select
End With

nrng.DataBodyRange.Offset(off).ClearContents
nrng.DataBodyRange.Offset(off).Columns(col).Resize(, res).Value2 = orng.DataBodyRange.Offset(off).Columns(col).Resize(, res).Value2

Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & sha.Name & "..."
End Sub
```

The problem arises when working with two different workbooks because the Listobject `orng` is not successfully set for the old workbook. I have tried different variations including activating the old workbook first, but none worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `sha` as **worksheet object**, it must have always be either from owb or nwb.

To correct it, you can use `sha.name`

```
With nwb
    Set nrng = sheets(sha.name).ListObjects(lis)
    nrng.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```

Otherwise, you can pass the worksheet name as a **String**

And bind the listobject this way

```
With owb
    Set orng = Sheets(sha).ListObjects(lis)
    orng.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With

With nwb
    Set nrng = Sheets(sha).ListObjects(lis)
    nrng.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```